# Can I separate a git repository into "bundles" containing their own branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control, project, project-management

**Here's a TLDR of my situation:**

--> ***V1*** of project was cleared for ***V2*** which will keep most of ***V1***'s code

--> ***V1*** is now light version of ***V2*** and needs version control going forward

> *v1 branches (current)*
>
> > ***main*** > dev > backup

--> ***V2*** needs to be delivered in three finalized branches to be released iteratively to users over time

> *v2 branches (planned)*
>
> > ***v1 main*** ---> v2 main > v2 dev >>>
> > v2(1) > v2(2) > v2(3)

Goals are:

- Deliver **V1** as a release with possibility to develop further
- Deliver **V2** as a bundle of 3 branches, zipped as 1 release
- Keep all in same project directory/repo for synchronization of node_modules + deps, easy delivery, and my own sanity

Is there a way to do this w/o a hard fork into a separate repo?

```
      repo
      /  \
     /    \
   [v1]  [v2]
    |      |                 
   b1      b1, b2
   b2      | 
   b3      | 
   |       + 
  {r1}    | r1  |
   |      |  r2  |---> zip
  zip     |   r3  |
```

Comment: *Bundle* is a Git term, as in what `git bundle` produces. Presumably you don't mean that...?

Comment: [Worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)?

Comment: @torek that's why I put the word in quotes, from what I've read I can't gather if it's the best route for this situation but high probability that it is and I'm overthinking it.

Comment: @phd I saw those too, not sure which is best overall I guess - don't want to pick one and end up in a mess